# Message Prompts not showing on Mobile Device

Tags: google-apps-script, google-sheets, mobile

I have some script for my Google Sheet that returns a message prompt to the user when an action is completed...

```
Browser.msgBox('Inspection has been ADDED',
             'Grower: ' + strIEGrower + '\\n' + 
             'Farm: ' + strIEFarm + '\\n' +
             'Block: ' + strIEBlockNumber + '\\n' +
             'Crop: ' + strIECropType,Browser.Buttons.OK);
```

It works fine when using the sheet on a desktop. But when I use it on a Mobile device the prompt does not show the prompt and my script errors with a timeout. I have tried using the...

```
SpreadsheetApp.getUi().alert('Complete');
```

It does not display either. Any help to display a message pop-up on a Mobile device would be appreciated.

Comment: That's been my experience as well.